# SubmitChanges won't work

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, database, linq

I've been searching for a solution to this for way too long and I would really like for this to work.

I'm trying to submit to a database but the changes won't happen even though the entire function executes.

At the top of the file I have this:

```
    DBContextDataContext n_db = new DBContextDataContext();
    UserRepository u_rep = new UserRepository();
```

Here is the function (line 280):

```
    public void FixWinRatio(int gameID)
    {
        //
        IEnumerable<BLGame> games = GetBLGameInfo(gameID);

        foreach (BLGame item in games)
        {
           Stat stats = u_rep.GetUsersStats(item.userID, 2);
            if (item.points >= 6)
            {
                 stats.wins += 1;
            }
            else
            {
                 stats.losses += 1;
            }
            n_db.SubmitChanges();
        }
    }
```

Nothing happenes, it all executes and the values change (stats.wins gets +1 or losses depending on points)

I've also tried this:

```
            n_db.Stats.Attach(stats, true);
            n_db.SubmitChanges();
```

Nothing.

Appreciate the time you take!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your UserRepository needs to use the same DataContext.  Since you don't pass it into the UserRepository ctor, I'm assuming it creates a 2nd DataContext which won't work.

Comment: I've been working on this problem for some time and I am way to tired to have logical thoughts of any size right now.
Now I can finally go to sleep with this off my mind.
Thank you so much.

Comment: @thefiloe A bit cynical are we? I'm working on a project that I've been working on with others for almost 3 weeks each day at least 8 hours. We are now on our final day and worked from 8 am to 2 am last night. All the above is true. Don't make assumptions you know nothing about.